# Admob onAdLoaded was Called But nothing is shown in screen

Tags: android

i was trying to use Admob using sample test id they have given. I've added maven repository in project level build.gradle and implemented play services ads in app build.gradle. when i run the app. onAdLoaded method was called. but there is nothing on my screen. i have tried with my own unique ad id too. but the result is same. please help

> Main Activity

```
 package com.twotwotwo.dip.admobtry;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        AdView mAdView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

            mAdView = new AdView(this);
            mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

            mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                    showToast("Ad loaded");
                    if (mAdView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                    if(errorCode == AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR){
                        showToast(" Something happened internally");
                    } else if(errorCode == AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST){
                        showToast("The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.");
                    } else if(errorCode == AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR){
                        showToast("The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.");
                    } else if(errorCode == AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL){
                        showToast("The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                    // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
                    // covers the screen.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                    // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
                    // to the app after tapping on an ad.
                }
            });
        }

        private void showToast(String message){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You Have To Add Payment Details in Admob Account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing this line

```
mAdView=(AdView) findViewbyid(R.id.adView)
```

Comment: Thanks. i missed that. Thanks a lot

Comment: in my case I am not missing this line and still having no add even i have got call back of on ad loaded

Answer (score 3):

You haven't attached ad with your main view. To do that first create a Linear Layout and then attach your ad with that Linear layout.

```
LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewbyid(R.id.adContainer);

MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        mAdView = new AdView(this);
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Place the ad view.
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
adContainer.addView(mAdView, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using View Binding, make sure you use

```
mAdView = binding.adView
```

instead of `mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)`